# How to find all the tables in database Teradata with specific column names in them?

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I have 2-3 different column names that I want to look up in the entire DB and list out all tables which have those columns. Any easy query?

I have seen [solution for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-to-%20find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-%20names-in-them), which won't work here because TD as far as I know don't have schemes, but instead I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853013/retrieving-column-and-other-metadata-information-in-teradata).

And tried this code:

```
SELECT TableName
FROM DBC.COLUMNS
WHERE DatabaseName = 'DB_NAME' and
ColumnName in ('col1', 'col2')
```

But surely subquery must be used to get TableName, because  DBC.COLUMNS doesn't have that field. Any further ideas?

Comment: `DBC.Columns` seems to be what you are looking for: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035_1092_111A/Views_Reference.015.134.html#ww25068441

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
SELECT tablename
FROM dbc.columnsV
WHERE ColumnName in ('col1', 'col2')
```

Comment: I updated my question, my chief says that sub query must be used

Comment: @Rocketq . . . of course the `tablename` is in the table.  Being told to use a subquery is counter-productive.

Comment: You right, it's in the table, I checked  `show select* from DBC.Columns`

Comment: Please change the view to **dbc.ColumnsV**, dbc.Columns is an old legacy version, deprecated since TD12. Starting with TD14.10 it might return wrong results if object names longer than 30 characters are used...

Answer (score 4):

This query works with me :

```
SELECT  DatabaseName,
        TableName,
        CreateTimeStamp,
        LastAlterTimeStamp
FROM    DBC.TablesV
WHERE   TableKind = 'T'
and     DatabaseName = 'YOUR_SCHEMA'
ORDER BY    TableName;
```