# Get distinct values of all the columns for more than 50 tables

Tags: sql, teradata

I have to get distinct values of all the columns for more than 50 tables in Teradata, is there any easy way to do that?

I don't want to keep on typing

```
select count(*), count(distinct A), count(distinct B), ....... 
from xyz;
```

Comment: read this then reconsider your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853013/retrieving-column-and-other-metadata-information-in-teradata  "dynamic sql" springs to mind

Comment: for executing dynamic sql look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13896108/2067753

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `Distinct` you may try `GroupBy`.

Comment: Please consider explain a bit more.